# How to store SharedPreferences in specific folder and get it?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, storage

This is my code to store a value in sharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences("My_Table_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString("my_key", "how Are You Bro...");
    editor.apply();
    editor.commit();
```

and I want to save it like this

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/.System/My_Table_Name");

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(file, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString("My_Key", "how Are You Bro...");
    editor.apply();
    editor.commit();
```

how can I do this?

```
 getSharedPreferences(File file, int mode);
```

This method is available, but it's been removed. Earlier I've tried to copy this file, but for this method the app needs super user permission (rooted device).

What should I use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is There A Way To Store SharedPreferences to SDcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43312275/is-there-a-way-to-store-sharedpreferences-to-sdcard)

Comment: I do not think there is a way of doing that. SharedPreferences bydefault saves at `/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/`.

Comment: but SharedPreferences block "getSharedPreferences(File file, int mode);" this  method some time before so may be is there any other solution available

Comment: `Earlier I've tried to copy this file, but for this method the app needs super user permission (rooted device).`. No. Not at all. An app can easily copy its shared preferences files to external storage.

Comment: thanks bro it's working well for me and thank you for save my time....